# An exact sequence which does not split

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, modules

Let $X$ and $Y$ be indecomposable modules over a finite dimensional algebra and let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a non-zero morphism which is neither a monomorphism nor an epimorphism.

Suppose that it is possible to find a module $Z$ and morphisms $f'' \colon X \to Z$ and $g'' \colon Z \to Y$ such that
$$
0 \longrightarrow X \xrightarrow{(f' f'')} Im f \oplus Z \xrightarrow{(g' g'')} Y \longrightarrow 0
$$
is an exact sequence, where $f'$ is the corestriction of $f$ to its image and $g'$ is the inclusion.

How can I show that this sequence does not split?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $Y=A\oplus B$ with $A\neq 0$ and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be any map with image $B$.  Let $Z=X\oplus A$.  Map $X$ to $Z$ as inclusion on the first factor and $Z$ to $Y$ as $-f$ on $X$ and he identity on $A$.  Then your sequence is easily seen to split, which is why you can't show that it doesn't.

Comment: $Y$ must be indecomposable.

Comment: Yes, I was just coming back to comment that my example doesn't work because my $Y$ isn't indecomposable, and saw that you'd beaten me to it.  So why do you expect this to be true?

Comment: It seems that $f"$ must be injective and that $g"$ must be surjective. If there is a section of $(f',f")$ then use that $End(X)$ is local?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ finite-dimensional? If so, then @WilberdvanderKallen's suggestion works. Or you can use the Krull-Schmidt Theorem: if the sequence splits, then $X\oplus Y\cong\operatorname{Im}(f)\oplus Z$, but $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ can't be isomorphic to either $X$ or $Y$ since it has smaller dimension than both.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, in fact I'm not sure if is this always the case. 
I'd like to prove that all coordinate morphisms are non-zero
and since $X$ and $Y$ are indecomposable it is possible to prove this if the sequence does not split.

Comment: Sorry @JeremyRickard, I did forget to say that $X$ and $Y$ are finite dimensional. But I still don't know why
$X \oplus Y \cong Im f \oplus Z$ implies that $Im f$ is isomorphic to $X$ or to $Y$.

Comment: @MarceloSilva: The Krull-Schmidt Theorem implies that every direct sum decomposition of $X\oplus Y$ into indecomposable modules has two summands isomorphic to $X$ and $Y$. But $\operatorname{Im}(f)\oplus Z$ can be refined to a direct sum decomposition into indecomposables.

Comment: @JeremyRickard: I guess I didn't write down properly my question. I don't know if I can refine $Im f \oplus Z$
to a decomposition into indecomposable modules because $\oplus$ is an external direct sum. And supposing that the decomposition of $Im f \oplus Z$ into indecomposable modules
is $X' \oplus Y'$, if $X'$ is contained in $Im f$, then we have a contradiction; but if $X'$ has non-zero intersection
with $Im f$ and $Z$, then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @MarceloSilva: Every finite-dimensional module has a decomposition into indecomposables. If $\operatorname{Im}(f)=M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_m$ and $Z=N_1\oplus\dots\oplus N_n$ are such decompositions, then $M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_m\oplus N_1\oplus\dots\oplus N_n$ is a decomposition of $\operatorname{Im}(f)\oplus Z\cong X\oplus Y$.